# Symfony Form Dropdown list with numbers in a specific interval

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

In my Symfony 4 project teachers can give grades to students. I implement it with a FormBuilderInterface. I'd like to have a dropdown list with numbers from min 1 to 5.

I tried this way:

```
 $form->add("grade_value",  ChoiceType::class, array('choices' => array(
            '0'=>'1',
            '1'=>'2',
            '2'=>'3',
            '3'=>'4',
            '4'=>'5'
        )));
```

also tried with this array:

```
'choices' => array(
            '1',
            '2',
            '3',
            '4',
            '5'
        )
```

But the labels getting values from 0 to 4.
How do I get the correct labels?
Also I'd rather use numbertype.
Is there a way to accomplish it with numbertype specifying a range? How?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'choices'  => [
    'label' => value,
],
```

So In your case proceed as following

```
$form->add("grade_value",  ChoiceType::class, array('choices' => array(
    '1'=>'1',
    '2'=>'2',
    '3'=>'3',
    '4'=>'4',
    '5'=>'5'
)));
```

Answer (score 0):

With `range()`:

```
$form->add('grade_value', ChoiceType::class, [
    'choices' => array_combine(range(1, 5), range(1, 5)),
]);
```